# How to parse "2019-09-19 04:03:01.770080087 +0000 UTC" timestamp

Tags: go, time, timestamp, utc

How would I parse this timestamp?

`"2019-09-19 04:03:01.770080087 +0000 UTC"`

I've tried the following:

```
formatExample := obj.CreatedOn // obj.CreatedOn = "2019-09-19 04:03:01.770080087 +0000 UTC"
time, err := time.Parse(formatExample, obj.CreatedOn)
check(err)
fmt.Println(time)
```

But all I get as output is:

`0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time format you pass to parse is not an "example" format. Each time field has a distinct value:

```
Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006
```

For instance, if you want to describe the year in your format, you *have* to use 2006. So your format must be:

```
2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000000 -0700 MST
```

Answer (score 0):

> [Parse](https://golang.org/src/time/format.go?s=24961:25007#L801) parses a formatted string and returns the time value it represents. The layout defines the format by showing how the reference time, defined to be
>
> `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006`
>
> would be interpreted if it were the value; it serves as an example of the input format. The same interpretation will then be made to the input string.

```
formatExample := "2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999999 -0700 MST"
```

https://play.golang.org/p/APkXHUAhMQ3

Answer (score -1):

A little dab'll do ya

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    layout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST"
    t, _ := time.Parse(layout, "2019-09-19 04:03:01.770080087 +0000 UTC")
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Outputs:

`2019-09-19 04:03:01.770080087 +0000 UTC`